# Octave leasqr only doing one iteration

Tags: octave, best-fit-curve

As I'm trying to fit a function to some experimental data, I've written a function with three inputs, three parameters and one output:

```
qrfunc = @(x, p) exp(-1*p(1)*x(:,1) - p(2)*x(:,2))+p(3)*x(:,3)+20;
```

When I generate some input and output values:

```
pS = [0.5; 0.3; 0.3];
x1 = [1 1 1; 1 1.1 1; 1 1.1 1.1; 2 1.2 2];
y1 = qrfunc(x1, pS);
```

And call the leasqr function:

```
pin =[1; 1; 1];
[f1, p1, kvg1, iter1, corp1, covp1, covr1, stdresid1, Z1, r21] = leasqr(x1, y1, pin, qrfunc, 0.0001);
```

This works correct, the function makes 7 iterations and provides the right outputs.

But when I load x1 from my experimental data (a text file with three columns, about 1500 lines) as well as my y1 (a text file with the same amount of lines) and run the same function, it only makes one iteration, and does not change the parameters.

It even shows that the error margins are very high:

```
sqrt(diag(covp1))
ans =
3.0281e+004
3.7614e+005
1.9477e-002
```

What am I doing wrong? There are no error messages, no 'Convergence not achieved' or anything like that...

Edit:
The data is loaded with the command:

```
load "input.txt"
load "output.txt"
```

Proof of loading:

```
size(input)
ans =
 1540      3
```

The first few lines from my input file:

```
10    0.4    5
20    0.4    5
30    0.4    5
40    0.4    5
50    0.4    5
```

The second and third parameters have different values further down the line.

Comment: Check the data types and sizes of `x1` and `y1` after you load them from your text file. I also suggest including the code you are using to load them and perhaps a snippet of the text files (the first 5 lines or something)

Comment: Okay, added the data... Although I believe my problem is that my function does not work well with my data. I tried to fiddle around with the parameters by hand, and it had surprisingly little effect, so I guess I have to go back and redefine my function...